# Mongo query data that not in range - not between

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I try to query some data that is not between integer range, I have some problems with that.

For now i managed to query "between" range:

```
{ '$where': "#{some_method(field)} <= #{value[1]} && #{some_method(field)} >= #{value[0]}" }
```

I need to search for data that is not in the range provided. How can I do that?

Comment: *...I have some problems with that* .. well it would probably help if you told us what those problems were. And why show the 'between' query? We're interested in the query you tried that **doesn't** work, not the one that does work.

Comment: Well Sebastian, thing is that i have no idea how "not between" query should look like ..

Comment: Did you even try to read the docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a query using `$or` operator to get documents, not in a specific range.

Eg. The following query will give you documents which values are not between 50 to 100.

```
db.getCollection('collection_name').find({$or:[{"some_field":{$lte:50}},{"some_field":{$gte:100}}]})
```